# Clicking on file input in a react-bootstrap Dropdown does not open the borwser's Open file dialog

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to put an `<input type=file/>` field into a bootstrap DropDown component. It renders correctly, but if I click on it it does not open the native file chooser of the browser.

I suspected that maybe the input component gets re-rendered when I click on it, and so the file chooser does not have a chance to run, but as far as I can tell there no re-rendering happens.

See the below example:

https://jsfiddle.net/0hmtkhpg/144/

Comment: Clicking the "select file" is triggering the onSelect of the MenuItem instead of opening a file dialog. I would put the file select in an accordion or even in the open instead of making Dropdown bend.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately it is a user request to put the file import in the dropdown :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop the event from bubbling up:

```
<input type=file onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}/>
```

Comment: This helped. But can I know why this is necessary?